# Not able to use GET followers/ids with Abraham OAuth

Tags: php, twitter

I was using the deprecated `statuses/followers` 1.0 of Twitter's API. Now I would like to test out the new 1.1 version `followers/ids` . But, I keep getting a blank page whenever I use the 1.1

Library: Abraham's PHP OAuth Library.

Example:

```
$parm = array('screen_name'=>'MYTWIT');
$followers =$oauth->get('followers/ids', $parm);
for ($i = 0 ; $i < count($follow) ; $i++)
{
    echo $followers[$i]->screen_name;
}
```

Am I doing something wrong here?

Comment: Above your `for` loop, try `var_dump($followers)` to debug what's going on.

Comment: We can't be much more help until you tell us **what library** you are using?

Comment: @Jimbo, I've mentioned in the title I'm using Abraham's OAuth library . I'll update my post. I'll try that Rob as soon as I get back.

Comment: Cool, nice one, good luck!

Comment: @RobW I see an array list of ids e.g. ` ids object(stdClass)#10 (5) { ["ids"]=> array(106) { [0]=> int(1482870852) [1]` However, I'm not able to see the data without `var_dump using `$followers['ids']`

Comment: I think you're looping over them wrong then. Try doing: `foreach($followers as $follower) { echo $follower->screen_name; }` Otherwise, can you post more of the result set from the `var_dump()`?